# JavaFX: What is wrong with the "Make controller" option in scene builder?

Tags: copy, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Everything started when I updated my JavaFX version:

When I click on "Make Controller" option in my FXML file, there are some kind of "extra updates", which cause that after 2 times I click on this option I get something like:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorWarrning" prefHeight="356.0" prefWidth="600.0"
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2"
fx:controller="GUI.Addons.Alerts.WarrningGUIController"
fx:controller="GUI.Addons.Alerts.WarrningGUIController"> <---- 2 TIMES! :(
<children>
```

Additionally there is no `.bak` file which was automatically created next to my FXML file when I was modifying it in Scene Builder.

Could someone tell me what is happening?

Comment: A bug is happening, you log bugs in SceneBuilder at: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com

Answer (score 0):

use
 `<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorWarrning" prefHeight="356.0" prefWidth="600.0"
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
fx:controller="GUI.Addons.Alerts.WarrningGUIController">`